# ember-truth-helpers - not able to get eq condition work

Tags: ember.js

On select component, I am not able to get the max value as selected.
my model of : `selectedCreditCard.matchingTenure` is an array like : `["12", "24", "36", "48", "61"]` from this, I am trying to set the max value as the default.

Max tenure is {{maxTenure}} //works fine. getting 61,

while compare for `selected` not getting the any value. any one help me here?

```
{{#rdc-form-select label="Instalment Duration" 
        labelPosition="left"
        options=selectedCreditCard.matchingTenure
        selected=(eq  getMatchingTenure selectedCreditCard.matchingTenure ) //not works
        searchEnabled=false
        renderInPlace=true
        class="installment-duration"
        onchange=(action 'selectATenure' ) as |data|}}
        {{data}}
    {{/rdc-form-select}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set max value as default selected outside the component by using `Ember.computed.max` and then bind it and use it inside the component.

Checkout this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/c76232f878f5bbaf48530c63f5319d56?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C).